# Java - Cannot Find symbol class concurrent

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, package

I have the following Java class:

```
import java.util.concurrent;

public class Test{


    public static void main(String[] args){
            ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                    ex.execute(new PeerThread(i+1));
            }


    }
```

}

For some reason, .concurrent does not import correctly. Instead, it gives me the error:

```
import java.util.concurrent;
            ^
symbol:   class concurrent
location: package java.util
```

Of course, it also gives me an error related to the usage of Executor, but that is to be expected if it can't find the concurrent package.

I downloaded the latest version of the SDK as well as the latest version of regular Java (as I was unsure whether or not this mattered).

java -version reports java 1.7.0_51.

http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp reports Java 7 51 as well.

If it matters, I am running Mac OSX 10.9.1.

I'm sure it is something stupid.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: that should be `Executors`

Comment: Yeah, that error came up afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: I also edited the question in case anyone else searches for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just forgot the star to import all classes in the package `java.util.concurrent`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

Otherwise it thinks `concurrent` is a class to be imported from `java.util`, and of course it does not exist.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I have not worked with Java for a while. I will confirm your answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Answer (score 2):

`java.util.concurrent` is a package not Class.So use Specific class name to import from this package or else use *.
For example
use `import java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService;`
 or
`import java.util.concurrent.*;`